# sql find name with letter

Tags: mysql, sql

In a list of name I want to select names with only few letters.
I've saw something like that but it doesn't work in my sql procedure[image]

```sql
OR identite LIKE `%`+v_nom+`%`;
```

v_nom is an input variable

Comment: LIKE ('%'+v_nom+'%');

Comment: They should wire keyboards up with a small electric charge that discharges any time someone posts a picture of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mysql `+` is not the concatenation operator, use the function `concat()`.
Also instead of backticks use single quotes:

```
OR identite LIKE concat('%', v_nom,'%');
```